# Transforming object data in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, format

I've got an issue transforming data in JS.

The data looks like this :

```
const data = [
  {
    "idPopulation": 1,
    "namePopulation": "Population 1",
    "idStrategy": 1,
    "nameStrategy": "Strategy 1",
    "priority": 1
  },
  {
    "idPopulation": 1,
    "namePopulation": "Population 1",
    "idStrategy": 2,
    "nameStrategy": "Strategy 2",
    "priority": null
  },
  {
    "idPopulation": 1,
    "namePopulation": "Population 1",
    "idStrategy": 3,
    "nameStrategy": "Strategy 3",
    "priority": 2
  },
  {
    "idPopulation": 2,
    "namePopulation": "Population 2",
    "idStrategy": 1,
    "nameStrategy": "Strategy 1",
    "priority": null
  },
  {
    "idPopulation": 2,
    "namePopulation": "Population 2",
    "idStrategy": 2,
    "nameStrategy": "Strategy 2",
    "priority": null
  },
  {
    "idPopulation": 2,
    "namePopulation": "Population 2",
    "idStrategy": 3,
    "nameStrategy": "Strategy 3",
    "priority": 1
  },
  {
    "idPopulation": 3,
    "namePopulation": "Population 3",
    "idStrategy": 1,
    "nameStrategy": "Strategy 1",
    "priority": 1
  },
  {
    "idPopulation": 3,
    "namePopulation": "Population 3",
    "idStrategy": 2,
    "nameStrategy": "Strategy 2",
    "priority": 2
  },
  {
    "idPopulation": 3,
    "namePopulation": "Population 3",
    "idStrategy": 3,
    "nameStrategy": "Strategy 3",
    "priority": 3
  }
]
```

I need to transform it into this for it to be usable in by front-end package (https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/editing/):

```
const testRows = [
    {
      nameStrategy: 'Strategy 1',
      priorityPopulation1: 1,
      priorityPopulation2: null,
      priorityPopulation3: 1,
    }, 
{...}]
```

I'm trying to reduce and stuff but can't figure it out yet. So far, I've done this :

```
const result = data.reduce((groupedStrat, strat) => {
  const stratName = strat.nameStrategie;
  if(groupedStrat[stratName] == null) groupedStrat[stratName] = []
    groupedStrat[stratName].push(strat)
    return groupedStrat
}, {})

console.log(result).
```

Let me know if my issue is clear and understandable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For you and for other new developers out there I have an advice: Don't use reduce. Break down the problem into simpler steps:

1. You have some data
2. You want some NewData that are generated from these data

to achieve that you have to read the old data and create the new data based on that info. Old data is in array format then a for loop is needed. For each of the array item you have to read the properties and store some temporary data based on that. After you have all these temporary data create a final array with the new formatted data.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "idPopulation": 1,
        "namePopulation": "Population 1",
        "idStrategy": 1,
        "nameStrategy": "Strategy 1",
        "priority": 1
    },
    {
        "idPopulation": 1,
        "namePopulation": "Population 1",
        "idStrategy": 2,
        "nameStrategy": "Strategy 2",
        "priority": null
    },
    {
        "idPopulation": 1,
        "namePopulation": "Population 1",
        "idStrategy": 3,
        "nameStrategy": "Strategy 3",
        "priority": 2
    },
    {
        "idPopulation": 2,
        "namePopulation": "Population 2",
        "idStrategy": 1,
        "nameStrategy": "Strategy 1",
        "priority": null
    },
    {
        "idPopulation": 2,
        "namePopulation": "Population 2",
        "idStrategy": 2,
        "nameStrategy": "Strategy 2",
        "priority": null
    },
    {
        "idPopulation": 2,
        "namePopulation": "Population 2",
        "idStrategy": 3,
        "nameStrategy": "Strategy 3",
        "priority": 1
    },
    {
        "idPopulation": 3,
        "namePopulation": "Population 3",
        "idStrategy": 1,
        "nameStrategy": "Strategy 1",
        "priority": 1
    },
    {
        "idPopulation": 3,
        "namePopulation": "Population 3",
        "idStrategy": 2,
        "nameStrategy": "Strategy 2",
        "priority": 2
    },
    {
        "idPopulation": 3,
        "namePopulation": "Population 3",
        "idStrategy": 3,
        "nameStrategy": "Strategy 3",
        "priority": 3
    }];

    //start reading and storing temp data 
    var strategies = {};//here store by strategy
    for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
       var item = data[i];
       if( !strategies[item.idStrategy] ){ //define the strategy
           strategies[item.idStrategy] = [];
       }
       //add item to strategy
       strategies[item.idStrategy].push(item);
    }

    //create converted data from temp data 
    var convertedData = [];
    
    for(var strategyId in strategies){
        var items= strategies[strategyId];
        var convertedItem = {
            nameStrategy: items[0].nameStrategy //get it from the firs as all items have the same nameStrategy
            //priorityPopulation1: null, dont define these yet
            //priorityPopulation2: null,
            //priorityPopulation3: null,
        }

        for( var j=0; j<items.length; j++){
            var item = items[j];
            convertedItem["priorityPopulation" + item.idPopulation] = item.priority;
        }
        convertedData.push(convertedItem );
    }

    console.log( convertedData );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution but also and most importantly for the advices.